# Simple rewrite of a question to mathematical form

Tags: logic

Simple rewrite of a question

For all real numbers x with $x^2-3 x+2\leq 0$, $1\leq x\leq 2$

I am trying to put this into a better form,

Could someone give me feedback

[image]

: stands for: "Such that"

Im pretty sure this is completly wrong, but I would like feedback on how it should be written.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's only one variable, so there should only be one quantifier. I would go with something like:
$$
\forall x \in \mathbb R \text{, } ~~ [x^2 - 3x + 2 \leq 0 \implies 1 \leq x \leq 2]
$$

Answer (score 5):

The only thing about

> For all real numbers $x$ with $x^2-3 x+2\leq 0$, $1\leq x\leq 2$

that seems to need improvement is that having just a comma between the formulas makes it difficult at a glance to see where one formula ends and the next begins. The standard solution for that is to insert a spacer phrase to get something like

> For all real numbers $x$ with $x^2-3 x+2\leq 0$, it holds that $1\leq x\leq 2$.

There! Eminently mathematical and readable.

The moral of this story here is that "more symbolic" (or even "less accessible without special training") is **not** the same as "more mathematical". It is definitely useful for a mathematician to *know* how to express the claim purely symbolically -- and the other answer explains that -- but that doesn't mean that a mathematician *ought* to write as much as possible in symbols, except when they have a particular reason to.